# Is the VADER tool in python compatible with interview data?

Tags: python, nlp, sentiment-analysis

Based on what I read about VADER, it is based on social media and is meant to analyze data from social media. I don't know how extensive and generalizable the dictionary is. Would it be appropriate/valid/parsimonious/useful for transcribed interview data?

If not, is there a tool more compatible for that type of data? I tried a basic search, but it did not yield other tools.

Comment: You might also want to try framing this as a [speech emotion recognition](https://github.com/topics/speech-emotion-recognition) problem. A transcription is not going to capture tone of voice.